# Design Question : share manipulate Data between different Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 Activities:

- 1 master activity.
- 1 detail activity

I tried to provide a dataclass (serialized) to the child the common way with **Intents**.
But I figured out, when the dataclass becomes big (lots of text which can't be fetched from child) then it crashes.
I am looking for another design sharing the data and found only the way to use a **Singleton** for the hole app.

Is there a more elegant way to share a bigger dataclass between Activities?